# Is Filezilla sending files twice?

Tags: ftp, filezilla

When I try to transfer a directory containing Drupal 8.1.8 to my web server, FileZilla opens a dialog saying some files already exists:

[image: Target file already exists]

How can this be? The target directory was newly created, and empty before I started the transfer. Is FileZilla overwriting its own files, or can there be another reason?

Comment: How many retries did you pick in the settings?

Comment: I haven't changed it, but it's set to 2. Would FTP create a file at all if it does not succeed writing to it? Because if it might, then that sounds like a very plausible cause.

Comment: Check the log for the file name.